# Paypal Integration Post processing information

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have created a simple `button`, on a click of it direct it to the paypal site for the payment.

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="abhish_1347270213_biz@gmail.com" />

    <input type="Show" name="item_name" value="My painting" />
    <input type="Show" name="amount" value="10.00" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Buy!" />
</form>
```

Now what I am trying to do is to redirect to my own page with the transaction successful notification.

I have read websites articles but nothing is providing me with the Solution. Need help regarding to this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PayPal Instant Payment Notification (IPN), more information here: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/pdn/article_pdn_intro-outside.

Here's a code sample:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="alanb@alanb.com">
<input type="hidden" name="undefined_quantity" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="doodad from alanb.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="dd01">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="4.99">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://alanb.com/doodads/thanks.html">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://alanb.com/doodads/canceled.html">
<input type="image" border="0" name="submit" src="http://images.paypal.com/images/x-click-but5.gif" alt="Effectuez vos paiements via PayPal : une solution rapide, gratuite et sécurisée">
</form>
```

The trick is done by the "return" input element ;).

Another thing that helped me a lot when setting up PayPal Integral Evolution on my website, was this PDF: https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/FR/en_US/files/developer/IntegralEvolution.pdf. It documents all fields, possible values and how to use them.

Hope this helps,
Carl

Comment: Thank you sir. it work. Now i do the thorough study of Instant Payment Notication (IPN) Topic.

Comment: sir i have one thing to ask. can IPN works with a site on localhost. as i am trying to redirect to a site on localhost but is showing an error.

Comment: PayPal servers will redirect the user to your web page, consequently you need to be able to access the PayPal server... and the server to access the provided web page. Therefore, set-up your return url to a publicly accessible url!